# Error en FileProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException al usar FileProvider.getUriForFile()

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema al intentar compartir un fichero con otras aplicaciones usando FileProvider, el problema viene cuando uso `FileContent.getUriForFile()` pues me da el siguiente error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
    'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)'
    on a null object reference
```

En mi manifest tengo declarado mi FileProvider de esta forma:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    package="com.example.myapp...  
    <application  
        ...  
        <Provider  
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"  
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.providers.FileProvider"  
            android:exported="false"  
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">  
            <meta-data  
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"  
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>  
        </Provider>  
    </application>  
</manifest>
```

Mi archivo filepaths.xml dentro de mi directorio res/xml es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <files-path name="downloaded" path="downloaded/"/>  
</Paths>
```

Y dentro de mi clase donde quiero compartir un archivo hago lo siguiente:

```
public class ShareFiles extends AppCompatActivity {  
    // creo una variable global para acceder al authorities de mi Provider  
    private final static String MY_PROVIDER = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".providers.FileProvider";

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        ....  
        FloatingActionButton compartir = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.share_btn);  
        compartir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            // creo y escribo texto en el archivo que quiero compartir  
            File dir = new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "downloaded");  
            // me aseguro de que el directorio exista y de no ser así lo creo  
            if(!dir.exists()) {  
                dir.mkdir();  
            }  
            // ahora creo el archivo dentro del directorio  
            File file = new File(dir, "mi_nuevo_archivo.txt");  
            // aquí realizo todo el proceso de escritura que omitiré para no confundir  
            // es en el siguiente paso donde me da el error  
            Uri contentFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), MY_PROVIDER, file);  
            ...  
        }  
    });  
}
```

No entiendo bien cual es mi error pues según la línea del logcat el error se debe a que intento usar el método `getUriForFile()` con un objeto nulo haciendo referencia a alguno de los dos parámetros que especifica el mismo texto:

```
android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)'
```

El asunto es que por lógica se refiere al objeto `android.content.pm.PackageManager` que por la forma en que se construye el `getUriForFile()` este viene derivado del contexto que se le pasa usando `getApplicationContext()`.

Alguien sabe donde está el error o que estoy haciendo mal?
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Revisa [como formatear](http://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) por favor y repite conmigo: "Si tengo una `Excepction`, lo publico entero o a lo menos donde aparece mi propio código. Luego marco la línea donde esta el origen en mi código, y con suerte ya me puedo responder a mi mismo." ;)

Comment: @Stefan Nolde gracias por el enlace de referencia para el markdown, solo quiero que sepas que el formatear se me complica enormemente porque, a pesar de usarse markdown que es extremadamente sencillo, soy un programador ciego, por esto es que se me complica formatear y lo hago lo mejor que puedo, pero al no tener referencia visual no siempre me queda bien.  
Antes de hacer comentarios ácidos por favor considera si tu podrías programar sin poder ver...

Comment: No era un comentario ácido. Yo simplemente tengo un humor extraño. Usas un software que te cambia los textos en audio?

Comment: De acuerdo, igual una disculpa por mi reacción pero casi siempre los desarrolladores ciegos somos menospreciados...  
Si, uso un lector de pantalla, NVDA, junto con Android Studio 2.2.3 y con ayuda del Accessibility Bridge de Java. Acá puedes leer sobre eso si te llama la atención:  
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/accessibility.html

Comment: No lo menosprecio, todo lo contrario, lo encuentro impresionante. Pregunté por dos razones, primero para saber como respondo (a ratos me gusta explicar con artesanía ASCII, que en tu casi probablemente sería completamente inutil), y segundo porque estoy planificando una herramienta para ayudar en formatear preguntas para SOes y quiería preguntar si tienes pistas que podría considerar para hacer el uso facil especialmente para personas que tienen problemas de formatear manualmente.

Comment: podrías idear la forma de usar etiquetas de marcado para lenguajes específicos, de esa forma no hace falta formatear todo a mano, si pondremos un código de cierto lenguaje usamos una etiqueta para indicar el lenguaje y el parser hace el resto...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El manifesto de Android discrimina entre minusculas y mayusculas.

```
    <provider  
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"  
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.providers.FileProvider"  
        android:exported="false"  
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">  
        <meta-data  
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"  
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>  
    </provider>
```

ya sería una buena idea.

Ademas recomiendo que te costumbras a usar

```
        boolean creado = dir.mkdirs();
```

en vez de:

```
        if(!dir.exists()) {  
            dir.mkdir();  
        }
```

La carpeta se crea solamente si no ya existe.